# adding current searched results as a new row of a table

Tags: html, angularjs, asp.net-mvc

I have a search text box which will search the customer records from database. customer record is having 'name','age', 'address' and many more fields. I am searching with **single** customer name and displaying that customer details in a table.

After 1st search, if i search other customer name then current customer details are  replacing the previous search result in that table.

I want to display all the search result(i.e; previous, current) in a same table.

I am using angularjs. here is my search angular controller code

```
$scope.search = function () {
    var price = '{custName: "' + $scope.Prefix + '" }';
    var post = $http({
        method: "POST",
        url: "/api/Price/GetDetails",
        dataType: 'json',
        data: price,
        headers: { "Content-Type": "application/json" }
    });
    post.success(function (data, status) {
        $scope.Customers = data;
        $scope.IsVisible = true;
    });
    post.error(function (data, status) {
        $window.alert(data.Message);
    });
};
```

**html code**

```
<div class="controls">
                                    <input type="text" ng-model="Prefix" placeholder="Search Material..." class="form-control" /><br />
                                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-dark" ng-click="search()">Search</button>
                                </div>
```

**table html code**

```
<tbody ng-repeat="m in Customers">
                                                    <tr>
                                                        <td align="center">
                                                            <a class="btn btn-default"><em class="fa fa-pencil"></em></a>
                                                            <a class="btn btn-danger"><em class="fa fa-trash"></em></a>
                                                        </td>
                                                        <td class="hidden-xs">1</td>
                                                        <td>{{m.PM}}</td>
                                                        <td>{{m.Description}}</td>
                                                        <td>{{m.Hier}}</td>
```

how to display all the search results in that table

Answer (score 0):

You have to store the results in a variable and keep appending the new results to it. We can use Javascript's concat() function for that.

```
var dataAll = [];
$scope.search = function () {
    var price = '{custName: "' + $scope.Prefix + '" }';
    var post = $http({
        method: "POST",
        url: "/api/Price/GetDetails",
        dataType: 'json',
        data: price,
        headers: { "Content-Type": "application/json" }
    });
    post.success(function (data, status) {
        dataAll = dataAll.concat(data);
        $scope.Customers = dataAll;
        $scope.IsVisible = true;
    });
    post.error(function (data, status) {
        $window.alert(data.Message);
    });
};
```

Then you will also need a clear button to reset dataAll to [].

Comment: it is not populating any result. I am calling json result via api. I think it is object not any string or text.So, it is not displaying any result.

Comment: I have updated the answer. We were concatenating but not assigning the result back to dataAll. Please try now.